# How to log-in with LDAP and gnome-shell in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, gdm, gnome-shell, ldap

Now this is a very specific question that Google didn't help me, and I could not find it already answered on the site. I'll start by explaining the problems and symptoms, then ask the question.

> **OS:** Xubuntu 16.04.4 LTS x86_64
>   **DE:** GNOME 3.18.5

*I'll post more from Neofetch if needed.*

I installed GNOME on Xubuntu because I wanted to change from XFCE to GNOME.

```
sudo apt install -y gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-panel ubuntu-gnome-default-settings ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers gnome-colors breathe-icon-theme
```

Here's the problem.

When I boot the computer, it opens `lightdm`. However, I can't log in on my GNOME desktop. If I try, it restarts `lightdm` and I return to the login prompt.

I have to log in using Xubuntu Session, which starts XFCE. Once started, I can log out, and I'm back to `lightdm`. This time, however, I can log in with my GNOME desktop, and everything works fine.

However, when I'm logged out for whatever reason (inactivity, `Super` + `L`), I'm back to `gdm3` *(or something that uses GTK, I can't confirm)*... And I can't login. I have an "Invalid password" error.

From there, I select "Other user...", and, suddenly, `lightdm`, which allows me to login without issue.

Now, the questions are :

1. How do I make it so `lightdm` works properly with GNOME when the computer boots?
2. How do I make it so `gdm3` works properly when the computer is locked?
3. How can I use `gdm3` by default, in a way that works with LDAP?
4. Can uninstall `gdm3` and only use `lightdm` without GNOME suffering from it? *(For example, being unable to lock the session)*